# Python 3.3 Writing A String From A List To A txt File

Tags: python, list, file, text, python-3.x

I am trying to write a string from a list to a text file over new lines

The string is stored in the list as follows

`name:emailaddress:mobilenumber`

I have a `repr` in a class which prints out a readable string to the screen so if the user wants to print the contacts to screen they will print as follows:

> Name - Email Address - Mobile Number

I can write to the text file as Name - Email Address - Mobile Number

but I want to write to the text file as follows:

```
Name
Email Address
Mobile Number
```

I'm not sure how to strip out the "-"

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
file = open("StaffData.txt", "w")
for contacts in staffList :
   file.write(str(contacts) + "\n")
file.close()
```

Any guidance would me much appreciated

Comment: why don't you try str1 = "Name - Email Address - Mobile Number".replace('-', ' ')?

Comment: You can do ' '.join(string.split('-'))

Comment: Does the mobile number have hyphens in it? If so, do those need to be retained?

Comment: Do you control the class? If so, can you make a copy of __repr__ that does the same thing except without the -s?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I used Roberto solution below and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could do something like:

```
with open("StaffData.txt", "wt") as file:
    for contacts in staffList :
       file.write("\n".join(str(contacts).split(' - ')) + "\n")
```

EDIT: According to last question update, every field goes in a different line